# Save onboarding in storage using Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I need to utilize app storage to save the state of onboarding, but I can't seem to figure it out with a @Published variable which I have, so I wanted to reach out and see if anyone know what I can do to switch things up.

So here is the code:

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showOnboarding = true
}
```

---

```
@main
struct MapGlider: App {
    @StateObject private var model = MainViewModel()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainScreenContainer(
                model: model,
                showOnboarding: $model.showOnboarding
            )
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct MainScreenContainer: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: MainViewModel
    @Binding var showOnboarding: Bool
    var body: some View {
        if showOnboarding {
            OnboardingView(
                model: model,
                showOnboarding: $model.showOnboarding
            )
        } else {
            MainView(model: model)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct OnboardingView: View {
    @Binding var showOnboarding: Bool
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                VStack {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem(alignment: .topTrailing)], content: {
                        Button(action: {
                            showOnboarding = false
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to click on the button inside `OnboardingView` and then set the app storage of showOnboarding to false, so next time the app runs, it can check `MainScreenContainer` and go directly to `MainView` if the storage is set to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your use case i would actually use `@AppStorage` property wrapper [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-appstorage-property-wrapper) which is a wrapper over `UserDefaults`, and i would get rid of that `ViewModel`. The code would look something like this:

```
struct MainScreenContainer: View {
    @AppStorage("show_onboarding") var showOnboarding: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        if showOnboarding {
            OnboardingView(
                model: model
            )
        } else {
            MainView(model: model)
        }
    }
}

struct OnboardingView: View {
    @AppStorage("show_onboarding") var showOnboarding: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                VStack {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem(alignment: .topTrailing)], content: {
                        Button(action: {
                            showOnboarding = false
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Razvan, would defining `@AppStorage("show_onboarding") var showOnboarding: Bool = false` as false in both views cause issues? Would you define false on just MainScreenContainer and then pass down the value and update it within the button later?

Comment: It won't cause any issues, that would be just a default value in case you don't have anything set, you could try this approach and see how it works

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that, appreciate the help.

Comment: And it is updated automatically in every view it is used based on that id "show_onboarding" that we give it

Comment: So with `@AppStorage("show_onboarding") var showOnboarding: Bool = false` it would look for the `show_onboarding` value first and if nothing is set, fall back to false?

Comment: exactly, that's how it works, and it also redraws the view when it's value is changed